# How to sample from 1 data set to match distribution of variable in another data set?

Tags: sampling

I have dataset 1 and another dataset 2. All values from dataset 2 are in dataset 1, however, dataset 1 has a variable X that does not match the distribution of data set 2. Is there a way I can sample from dataset 2 such that the variable X matches the distribution of dataset 1? I'm using python/pandas and I've tried to figure out someway using sklearn train_test_split using stratified sampling but I don't think I can use the distribution of one dataset here to sample from another.

Comment: To clarify, you have a dataset `A` without an `age` variable. And you have another dataset `B`, where you have persons but without an `age`. You want to sample from dataset `B`, but add an `age` to each person sampled from dataset `A`?

Comment: Hello. No sorry so in your example both datasets would have `age` but they are distributed differently. Dataset `A` might have more skew towards higher ages, and dataset `B` has a skew towards lower ages. I want to sample from `B` but have my sample match the distribution from `A`. So my sample would have the same proportion of higher ages than low ages as in dataset A.